# Application version is not set during Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, versioning

I have a WinForm App, using C# and SQL.
I have a particular form Load Event that returns me currentversion of My app.

Here is how it looks.

```
public Version assm
{
     get
     {
         return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
     }
}
```

I'm using the `assm` function to get release details like major version, minor, build etc.

```
label1.Text = assm.Major.ToString();
label5.Text = assm.Minor.ToString();
label6.Text = assm.Build.ToString();
label7.Text = assm.Revision.ToString();
```

But while loading the form, it gives the "Application identity is not set" Exception on the line: `return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;`

What could be the reason?

Furthermore is there any other way to get application version details?

Comment: was your application deployed using clickonce? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment is only valid for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute in your AssemblyInfo.cs, you can get that value using `FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion`. E.g.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
```

The value you put in `AssemblyInformationalVersion` can be anything you like really, it's not restricted to major.minor, etc. So values such as "1.5 beta 1", is totally valid.

See MSDN for more info [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productversion(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So to add the extra version info, you'll have an Assembly.cs that will include something like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.5 beta 1")]
```

Comment: It needs to be set using the `AssemblyInformationalVersion`. If it is not set, the value of `FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion` will be that of  the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute (which I suspect is "1.0.0.0").

Comment: Updated my answer a little further. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the assembly version using this:

```
public Version assm
{
  get
    {
      return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the assemblyinfo.cs version..in my this case its 1.2
but my publish version values are 1.5.2.1..
i want to display those in the label controls... any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

```
 public string GetVersion()
        {
            Version v = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            return " v." + v.Major + "." + v.Minor + "." + v.Build + "." + v.Revision;
        }
```